# shinyfiles folder selection breaks down when I press Input button

Tags: r, shiny

I tried to use the correct answer from   [Display selected folder path in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47719285/display-selected-folder-path-in-shiny)  but when I press "Input directory" button the whole app breaks down and gives me the following error:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7753
Warning: Error in $: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
  75: unlist
  72: observeEventHandler [C:\Users\makis\Documents\NVB/app.R#30]
   1: runApp
```

What may be the issue? Maybe happens only in my machine.

```
    library(shiny)
    library(shinyFiles)

    # Define UI for application that draws a histogram
    ui <- fluidPage( # Application title
      mainPanel(
        shinyDirButton("dir", "Input directory", "Upload"),
        verbatimTextOutput("dir", placeholder = TRUE)  # added a placeholder
      ))

    server <- function(input, output) {
      shinyDirChoose(
        input,
        'dir',
        roots = c(home = '~'),
        filetypes = c('', 'txt', 'bigWig', "tsv", "csv", "bw")
      )

      dir <- reactive(input$dir)
      output$dir <- renderText({  # use renderText instead of renderPrint
        parseDirPath(c(home = '~'), dir())
      })

      observeEvent(ignoreNULL = TRUE,
                   eventExpr = {
                     input$dir
                   },
                   handlerExpr = {
                     home <- normalizePath("~")
                     datapath <<-
                       file.path(home, paste(unlist(dir()$path[-1]), collapse = .Platform$file.sep))
                   })
    }

    # Run the application
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I attach my sesssioninfo below. Note that since I have loaded other packages in this working directory more packages that those I seem to use here are displayed.

```
 sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_1.1.0      shinyFiles_0.7.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.18    withr_2.1.2     crayon_1.3.4    digest_0.6.15   later_0.7.3     mime_0.5       
 [7] R6_2.2.2        xtable_1.8-2    jsonlite_1.5    git2r_0.23.0    magrittr_1.5    httr_1.3.1     
[13] rlang_0.2.1     curl_3.2        rstudioapi_0.7  promises_1.0.1  devtools_1.13.6 tools_3.4.1    
[19] httpuv_1.4.5    yaml_2.1.19     rsconnect_0.8.8 compiler_3.4.1  memoise_1.1.0   htmltools_0.3.6
>
```

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: What could be the issue based on the error I get?

Comment: Maybe you could add your `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: I attached it..

Comment: I am using `shinyFiles_0.6.2` and `shiny_1.0.5.9000` (I don't see your shiny version). Maybe you could try to rerun your code in a new session with only shiny and shinyFiles loaded.

Comment: It does not work even with the new github versions installed in a new wd. The problem seems to be in this line datapath <-
                   file.path(home, paste(unlist(dir()$path[-1]), collapse = .Platform$file.sep)) regarding the error message I get

Comment: I have shiny_1.1.0 . How can I get your version?

Comment: I think I got it from there https://github.com/rstudio/shiny.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177213/discussion-between-firmo23-and-mlavoie).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is answered on github: https://github.com/thomasp85/shinyFiles/issues/109

One needs to add the line: `req(is.list(input$dir))` to your observeEvent:

```
observeEvent(ignoreNULL = TRUE,
               eventExpr = {
                 input$dir
               },
               handlerExpr = {
                 req(is.list(input$dir))
                 home <- normalizePath("~")
                 global$datapath <-
                   file.path(home, paste(unlist(dir()$path[-1]), collapse = .Platform$file.sep))
               })
```

Comment: When I run this I get this error: `Warning: Error in <-: object 'global' not found
  [No stack trace available]`

Answer (score 0):

Worked with shinyFiles_0.6.2 and shiny_1.0.5